# How to converting from single to double and maintain precision

Tags: .net, floating-point

This little code blurb

```
    Dim s As Single = 1.15
    Dim d As Double = CDbl(s)
    Console.WriteLine(s)
    Console.WriteLine(d)
```

yields:

```
1.15
1.14999997615814
```

which is completely unexpected.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

ETA:

This isn't my bit of code, and it turns out the original input was coming in as a string "1.15", so they were converting it to single, then double.  Removing the single part made everyone happy.

Comment: Decimal "precision" in engineering terms is not easily met by a binary floating point system. Perhaps you meant displayed rounding? The "imprecision" you see is all in your mind.

Comment: If you need accuracy in non-integral math, then you're better off with the Decimal type.

Comment: Or using a rational type.  Or knowing how many sig digits you need to keep, and always rounding to that number after calculations, before changing types.

Comment: Btw, here is the C# version. http://ideone.com/2wDyMq

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language of computer science precision is given in terms of the size of the mantissa and exponent. It has nothing to do with "significant figures". Perhaps most confusing is the fact that you are viewing a **base 2** floating point number in **base 10**!

If you looked at the base 2 representation of the two values you would realize that they are not far apart.

The decimal 1.15 has a binary value of 1.00100110011001...*ad infinitum*. You get 23 bits of mantissa with `Single` and 52 bits of mantissa with `Double`. Obviously with finite precision the repetition in the mantissa will be cut off in different places.

If you would like the number to be displayed with the same base 10 representation you will have to live with a bit of slop unless you inform the string conversion routine to format it in a nicer fashion.

Comment: This answer fails to explain why the same numerical value is printed differently.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I can add more detail if you think this answer is confusing. However, the information given is sufficient.

Comment: The fact that “1.15” would be rounded differently when assigned to a `Single` and to a `Double` because their significands are different lengths is **not** the cause of the problem in this question, and this answer is incorrect to indicate that it is. In this question, the numerical values of `s` and `d` are exactly the same, because `d` was assigned with `Dim d As Double = CDbl(s)`, so it received the value **after** it had already been rounded to the shorter `Single` significand.

Comment: Additionally, the significands of `Single` and `Double` are 24 and 53 bits. They are partially encoded with 23-bit and 52-bit fields, but the significand includes an additional bit derived from the exponent field. (“Significand” is the preferred term; significands are linear, but mantissas are logarithmic.)

Answer (score 1):

Although `s` and `d` contain exactly the same numerical value, different numerals are displayed for them because different numbers of digits are used for `Single` and `Double` conversions to text.

`Console.WriteLine(s)` calls `Console.WriteLine(Single)` which produces the text representation of `s` using `Single.ToString` which converts using the format specifier “G” which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString). Similarly, `Console.Writeline(d)` calls `Double.ToString`.

According to the documentation, the maximum number of digits used is 7 for `Single` and 15 for `Double`. I do not see documentation specifying the actual number of digits used, just the maximum.

The statement `Dim s As Single = 1.15` sets `s` to the value 1.14999997615814208984375, because that is the `Single` value closest to 1.15. (The second closest is 1.150000095367431640625.) When you round that value to seven decimal digits, the result is “1.150000”. I presume .NET omits the trailing zeroes, yielding “1.15”.

When `d` is set to the same value and printed, 15 digits are used. When 1.14999997615814208984375 is rounded to 15 digits, the result is “1.14999997615814”.

So, there is no error when a `Single` is converted to `Double`. This is merely an illusion of display.

Note that there is generally an error when `Double` is converted to `Single`. Had you written `Dim d As Double = 1.15`, then `d` would be set to 1.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375, and I expect `Console.WriteLine(d)` would produce “1.15”. Converting `d` to `Single` would produce 1.14999997615814208984375.